# Unjustified increase of the image layers after ADD . sentences

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, docker

I'm using Docker (lxc-docker v1.3.0) to build my Rails web app image with Dockerfile as follow:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

<some sentences here>

WORKDIR /project

# gems install
RUN gem install bundler
ADD Gemfile /project/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /project/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install

# assets precopile
ADD Rakefile /project/Rakefile
ADD public /project/public
ADD vendor /project/vendor
ADD config/environments /project/config/environments
ADD config/application.rb config/boot.rb config/compass.rb config/environment.rb /project/config/
ADD app/assets /project/app/assets
RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile\
    && rm -rf /project/tmp/cache

# copy code
ADD . /project
```

**Docker history:**

```
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE
f5f96366b42f        3 minutes ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD dir:9b4e0c4a81a33fafdb4   32.06 MB
c01a13a10046        53 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD [rake beesor:boot:unico   0 B
31bc3e110665        53 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) EXPOSE map[8080/tcp:{}]       0 B
74e45052cc6e        53 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c mkdir -p /beesor/tmp/pids &&     m   0 B
5fed0de65918        53 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c bundle exec rake assets:precompile   25.16 MB
```

Then I can execute `docker build -t project .` But when I inspect image history (`docker history project`) I found something that take me an alarm about the last layer size, because my current directory only have **19.5MB** and last layer(referent of `ADD . /project`) appear with: **32.06 MB**. I don't know if this it's an issue or if it's the right behavior? I need some ideas about it.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong.  Every line in docker is a commit. an image, and overhead.   I'd optimize all those ADDS and kill the majority of them personally.   If you get your source in order, you should be able to do it in a single ADD +/-

Comment: @user2105103 I need only add my sourcecode(19.5 MB) and I don't know why the last layer appear with 32.06 MB.

Comment: I was talking about the 9 ADD statements in your Dockerfile.   If you really want to see what's going on -- do a docker diff

Comment: Are you sure `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` is not compiling something which adds the 25 mb?

Comment: @ZeissS I'm not sure because, the last layer it's after RUN asset:precompile...in theory the last layer only rewrite /project with files.

Comment: @user2105103 I don't know how make docker diff between docker layers.